# How make a simple approve entry plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I need a simple plugin for approve access to an entry for specific users. Like this:

- array with approved entries ids for the currentUser

> GetApprovedEntries(currentUser.id)

- Approve entry for a user (from pending entry ids array)  and add to approvedEntries array and remove from pending array

> ApproveUserForEntry(user.id, entry.id)

- get all approved users for a specific entry

> getApprovedUsers(entry.id)

- Ask for entry access and add to pending array of the user

> AskEntryAccess(currentUser.id, entry.id)

How I do this (add an array to a user), i am not a plugin developer.

Comment: How are you planning on specifying which users can access which entries?

Comment: The approved ids match to a channel groups and al other entries and channels have a relation to one of the groups. On a entry page I'll check  which group the entry has and if the group id has a match with the allow plugin array from the current user. If a match the user is granted otherwise he is denied.